# How to find out Microsoft Outlook Web access version?

Tags: outlook-web-access

I need to find out the version of particular installation ( [this one](http://mail.uminho.pt) ) of `Microsoft Outlook Web Access` only with normal user privileges.

I also know that the server has the following services:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
25/tcp  open  smtp
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
993/tcp open  imaps
995/tcp open  pop3s
```

It is possible? If so, how?

Comment: Is there any valid reason for this other than hacking?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare this version with the new one in a formal email, I need the version to get all the (*pre-historical*) features against the new version. ***Hopefully*** I can convince the "bosses" to upgrade this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get Microsoft's internal version number from the OWA web UI's About page.

Then compare to the chart here:

http://slicesofcomputer.blogspot.com/2014/04/what-exchange-server-version-is-my.html

Answer (score 3):

If you telnet into the SMTP Port (25) you will get the following server banner:

`Version: 6.0.3790.4675` this equals to exchange 2000 (version number list here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158530/en-us)

/edit: correcting myself: The version does not point to a native exchange - it could very well be a Small Business Server 2000